# What awaits an async action method's return?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

In ASP.NET MVC and Web API, an asynchronous action is a controller action method marked with the modifier `async`, e.g:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

This marks the action method as asynchronous, hence my nom de guerre of 'an async action', and it indicates that the method may contain 'awaited called to other `async` methods, and that it will not run full stop from top to bottom line of code. It also suggests that it's caller uses something like:

```
ActionResult result = await Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
```

Meaning that this call will wait for any little (or massive) asynchronous tasks spun off by `Login` to finish before properly returning the `ActionRsult`. We say that the caller is 'awaiting' on it's call to `Login`.  My question is what object makes that call in the second code block, and 'awaits the async action'>

I've never really cared what called an action, and awaited, a method before; I've always thought it to be rather close to the request-response pipeline, and on a asynchronous action, ignoring result filters, it pretty much goes straight to the browser.

Does this object that awaits action methods do so that it can call more of them and prevent backlog in the pipeline, or are the all just `async` so that we can await other tasks within them?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. Perhaps a code example would help.

Comment: The framework pipeline awaits the action.  Ultimately the purpose is to release resources which are otherwise awaiting other things (I/O, DB, etc.) so that the web server can handle more requests while other current requests are busy.

Comment: @mason Don't the tags suggest that you should know a bit about what I'm talking about. I know nothing about medicine, but I don't complain when I don't understand medial questions on fora.

Comment: @ProfK Your question originally stated "prevent backlog in the Philippine". I hope you can see why that would cause confusion. You also originally tagged the question with a framework that I don't believe is capable of using async action methods.

Comment: @mason My sincere apologies. There may be some very Goldbergesque and labyrinthine occasion when using synchronous action methods indeed causes a backlog in the Philippine, but lets pretend it's impossible.

Comment: Congratulations, @David, you understood exactly what miilions of other couldn't. At a guess I'd say you do a bit of ASP.NET development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> on a asynchronous action, ignoring result filters, it pretty much goes straight to the browser.

No; asynchronous actions are processed just like synchronous actions, and are at the same level of abstraction. They don't skip any filters.

The difference between synchronous and asynchronous methods are that synchronous methods are complete when they return to their caller; asynchronous methods return a task that completes when the method completes. For more information, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) post.

> Does this object that awaits action methods do so that it can call more of them and prevent backlog in the pipeline, or are the all just async so that we can await other tasks within them?

Both. The `async` keyword is necessary to use the `await` keyword, so from the action's perspective, `async` is required to await other tasks.

From the framework's perspective, it understands that when an action returns a task, it has not necessarily completed. Rather, the action will complete when the returned task completes. The framework hooks up a callback to that task that will send the response when that task completes.